# Domain for WordPress site in Ubuntu server

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, dns

I have a site that has a domain, when I open it using the domain name there are no styles and I can't log in(The user is in the DB though), but if I open it using the IP address everything works perfectly.  Any ideas about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the 'Wordpress URL' and 'Site Address URL' in general settings (Settings > General)